# LibGDX Problems with textures in 1st launch after installing

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I have a problem with my android app created with LibGDX. After 1st launch part of textures in game just disappear and only after relaunch (not hide and reopen) all works fine. It happens only 1 time currently after 1st launch after installing. If installing on installed app, all works fine.

I use atlas for textures, it is 2048x2048. In project I use AssetLoader class with static objects. I saw some tips, that problem may be with static, but then why part of textures normally load?

If somebody had this kind of problem give an advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It is not in AssetLoader ot Textures. When i load game objects, I also recreate data in phone resources, so when this data exists, all loads fine, but if it is 1st time and it needs to create this data on phone, it causes problems with loading resources. I just move "recreating data" to own function and now all work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is called **context loss**. Textures you load and create are unloaded automatically when you hide, and some of the context are lost between hide and reopen. Relaunching or killing active app after hide will destroy current JVM and when you open again it will be fresh launch and everything works fine.

To avoid this you can manually manage this situation by overriding pause() and resume() methods on ApplicationListener class (which is your main class extending ApplicationListener). You should unload/dispose assets on pause() and reload/create them on resume().

It's not the best but to give an idea you can see an implementation here in question's "EDIT:" part: [LIBGDX White textures in the first run on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23238681/libgdx-white-textures-in-the-first-run-on-android?rq=1)

But I strongly recommend to avoid static fields and use AssetManager class to load and get Textures, TextureAtlases and such other assets. And let it manage textures for you.

Take a look at: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets

Comment: Thank you, but rewriting pause and resume methods didn't help..
My game is mostly finished and AssetLoader class is huge. I know about AssetManager and going use it in next projects.

I think, that rewriting didn't help because of this loss causes not after hide and reopen, but only in 1st launch. After that i can hide and reopen my app as many times, as i can, and all will work fine..

Comment: Another strange thing is that my shop screen loads always fine and on it I can change game object textures, but when I return to menu screen or game screen, nothing changes. Maybe it is because AssetLoader.loadShop() I use everytime I create shop screen and dispose it everytime i close shop screen, but game and menu screen's objects have only in method create() AssetLoader.load() and in method dispose AssetLoader.dispose() (also now with your advice in pause method dispose() and in resume method load).

All music, sounds and fonts, and also even some textures, loaded fine and always work.

Comment: Did you avoid static fields?

Your shop screen loads always fine because as you said you are creating it again everytime it loads.

Comment: No, as i said, sadly I have already done all objects in AssetLoader static.. But my shop screen always reload only his own textures, and it also contains textures used in other screens and in it they work fine, unlike in menu screen and game screen. And also very strange, that it happens only 1 time after installation, and after that never happens.. May it be connected with local data or anything else? Because it is not lifecycle of app, it never happens after second launch.

Comment: I tried to make load and dispose of AssetLoader for menu and game screens as for shop screen, but it didn't help anyway. So it seems problem is not in AssetLoader..